# How to find the Fourier coefficients for a function defined by a csv file using the trapezoid rule in python?

Tags: python, numeric

I'm new to Python but have this homework assignment I'm not prepared for. Please help. 
I wrote:

```
import numpy as np 
X,Y = np.loadtxt("wavedata.csv", usecols=(0, 1), delimiter=",", unpack=True)
```

and defined functions for a_0, a_n, b_n, and the trapezoid rule. But the CSV file only has from values from 0 to 10. Don't Fourier coefficients need integration from -L to L? And how would I use the trapezoid rule here, or make functions computing the coefficients?

Any tips? Any chunks of the program you can share with me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear what you are asking--perhaps a more specific framing of the question would be helpful.

However,I will try to answer. The Fourier coefficients are used to describe a periodic function as a sum of a fundamental frequency (which is defined by the period); but for a non-periodic data set, we take the period to be infinity (i.e. the pattern may repeat, but in an infinite time away), and that defines the Fourier transform.

So I think what you may be looking for is the coefficients of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), which can be simply computed with `numpy.fft.fft()` (see their documentation for more details about how to use the function properly).